# Fragment which contains Dialog fragment Back Button Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have an Activity which contain Fragment. This fragment contain EditText and button.I used **setOnKeyListener for Edittext**.

```
    fragmentEdittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
    });
```

If I click a Button  in fragment I will call DialogFragment that also contain one EditText.I have used **setOnKeyListener for this Edittext also**. If I Press **Back button from DialogFragment  I will call dismiss()**. My problem is after DialogFragment dismissed  Fragment's  Edittext  Back event also triggered.
How to prevent Fragment's Editext Back Button triggering when i press Back Button from DialogFragment's Editext.

```
    dialogFragmentEdittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
                dismiss();
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
    });
```